# name dependent dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

For these two constructors:

```
public SomeClassWithDependency(IValidator<SomeClass> concrete1)
{
    ...
}

public SomeOtherClassWithDependency(IValidator<SomeClass> concrete2)
{
    ...
}
```

I currently try to use this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IValidator<SomeClass>>().ImplementedBy<Concrete1>().Named("concrete1"));
container.Register(Component.For<IValidator<SomeClass>>().ImplementedBy<Concrete2>().Named("concrete2"));
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if Concrete1 is always injected. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If your code is as-typed, you're naming both instances `concrete1` in your container.I don't know Windsor, but that doesn't look correct.

Comment: Thanks, sorry this was a typo, which is now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SubResolver](http://kozmic.net/2009/04/09/convention-based-dependency-injection-with-castle-microkernelwindsor/) that chooses, among multiple components registered for same type, the component registered with a name matching the parameter name.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit puzzled about how to use the ConventionBasedResolver in my scenario. A code example would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just seem to have to do add: container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ConventionBasedResolver(container.Kernel)); and it works (the order problem is resolved).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DependsOn` when you register the dependent classes to tell Windsor which instance to inject:

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<SomeClassWithDependency>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IValidator<SomeClass>, Concrete1>()),
    Component
        .For<SomeOtherClassWithDependency>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IValidator<SomeClass>, Concrete2>()));
```

This does somewhat break the concept of programming to an interface, and should probably used sparingly, but sometimes it's unavoidable.

Comment: This does not seem to work in my scenario. Cristiano Degiorgis's approach seems to work ...